# Normal approximation to a Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> A fair coin is tossed $40$ times. Let $S$ be the number of heads we observe. Find the probability of observing between $22$ and $25$ heads using a normal approximation.

Since this is a binomial distribution problem, we calculate:

$\mu = n \cdot p = 40 \cdot 0.5 = 20.$

$\sigma^2 = n \cdot p \cdot q = 40 \cdot 0.5^2 = 10 \Rightarrow \sigma = \sqrt{10}.$

What we're looking for is $P(22 \leq S \leq 25) = P(S \leq 25) - P(S \leq 22)$.

Using continuity correction, the area we're interested in is $P(S < 25.5) - P(S < 22.5).$

Now to calculate the $z-$Scores for $25.5$ and $22.5$:

$Z_{25.5} = \dfrac{25.5-20}{\sqrt{10}} = 1.74$ and $Z_{22.5} = \dfrac{22.5-20}{\sqrt{10}} = 0.79.$

Using the $z-$Score table we get:

$P(S < 25.5) - P(S < 22.5) = P(X < 1.74) - P(X < 0.79) = 0.9591-0.7852 = 0.1739.$

---

However, my textbook gives $0.278$ as the solution. Where's my mistake and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply continuity correction factor you have to enlarge the interval so you have to calculate

$$P(21. 5<S<25.5)=0.959-0.681=0.278$$